# RESTful web service error 500 on android

Tags: android, angularjs, json, spring, rest

Hello guys I'm new to restful service.
My friend created REST backend with Spring.
When I post this URL --> http://smartcar.tobaconsulting.com:9999/api/v1/login with postman or angularjs http.post, it's fine.
You guys can check it out in postman by including this body

```
{ "username":"alvin", "password":"alvin" }
```

and set content type to JSON (application/json).

But when I code to Android, why it's not working and return 500 error code.
My friend said that I'm not including header. I'm using loopj http library http://loopj.com/. Here is my android code

```
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("username", username);
        params.put("password", password);

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.post("http://smartcar.tobaconsulting.com:9999/api/v1/login", params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("status code: %d", statusCode));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d(TAG, String.format("status code: %d", statusCode));
            }
        });
```

Please help me guys. I trying to solve this problem for hours and haven't find any clue.
Thanks

Comment: I would personally suggest using Retrofit, but that's not relevant to your problem.

Comment: @greenapps its internal server error I guess he sending something which is unable to process by the server

Comment: @Alvin use SOUP Ui software and check the calls whether you are getting proper response and try in android

Comment: I know what 500 means. The question was for OP of course.

Comment: @raghavendra ok i'll try later.. thanks..

Answer (score 0):

i checked your URL no error in server response

> Access-Control-Allow-Credentials →true
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Methods →GET, POST, PUT, DELETE
>
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin →chrome-extension://mkhojklkhkdaghjjfdnphfphiaiohkef
>
> Access-Control-Expose-Headers →X-AUTH-TOKEN
>
> Content-Length →0
>
> Date →Thu, 07 Apr 2016 08:35:26 GMT
>
> Server →Apache-Coyote/1.1
>
> X-AUTH-TOKEN
>   →eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFsdmluIiwiZW1haWwiOiJhbHZpbkBhbHZpbi5jb20iLCJleHBpcmVzIjoxNDYwODgyMTI2MDc4LCJvd25lcmlkIjo2LCJteVJvbGVzIjpbIlVTRVIiLCJBRE1JTiJdfQ==.M9/71trIPbnXxCh7avSWBK42UDXUxWYXZrNOlHhO7iQ=

I would personally suggest using Volley lib for android, there is some useful method inside volley and google strongly recommended that
[Transmitting Network Data Using Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html)

Comment: yes it's working if you check the url in postman or using angular $http.post.. but why I can't get it worked on android.. am I missing something like I'm not including Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my request or something.. maybe i should try volley first

Comment: I checked with postman, is it a native android or cross platform app?

Comment: i think it's a cross platform app.. because my other friends developed website with angularjs with that back-end and it's working fine. I also developed with Ionic and it's alright. But when I write in native Android apps, I can't get it worked.. Could you help me writing some code in Jave ??

Comment: Sure :) wait i will share a snippet.

Comment: ok thanks man :) :) :).. my head is spinning to figure out how should I write the code.. Oh i forgot to mention this.. after requesting json to the backend, if the json correct, the backend will response X-AUTH-TOKEN.. please make sure that the code can return that token

Comment: Hi i just tried with postman its working, but in the case of i tried with restclent in firefox its still returning 500 internal server error

Comment: ohh i see.. i also got error 500 using restclient in firefox.. fidler also said that.. i'm gonna ask my friend about the backend that he created.. thanks for your help